# AWS Lambda for .net core using GitLab

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am new to gitlab and need to use it for pushing zipped lambda code written in .net core to s3 which will be later referenced by terraform.

Below is the step that works **WITHOUT** *GITLAB*

- Created a dotnet Core Lambda Application for DynamoDB using command -
  "dotnet new lambda.Dynamo" (standard template)
- Ran command dotnet lambda package => generated a zip file in release
  folder of the solution
- Wrote a terraform script which reference this zip file and ran
  terraform to create Lambda in AWS UI

*Now I need to achieve all this **USING** *GITLAB**

Below are the pseudo steps

- Create a new gitlab repo and upload .net core Lambda Application for
  DynamoDB
- add .gitlab-ci.yml =>

  ```
       A. This script should be able to create a zip file for the .net core project
       B. This script should be able to push the generated zip file to S3
  ```
- Have a terraform that references this Zip file from S3.

*Question 1 -* Does the above mentioned Pseudo Stepsfor gitlab makes logical sense?

*Question 2 -* Can I get some guidance on build script which can help in achieving the pseudo steps. Thanks!